# Get the string representation of a jquery DOM object's entire HTML

Tags: jquery, dom

I have had a bit of a look around and am having some difficulty solving a wee issue I am having.

I basically have a string of HTML, I convert that to a JQuery DOM object so that I can easily remove all elements that have a certain class using JQuery's .remove(). I.e.,

```
var radHtml = editor.get_html();

var jqDom = $(radHtml);

$(".thickbox", jqDom).remove();
$(".thickboxcontent", jqDom).remove();

editor.set_html(this.innerHTML);
```

NOTE: The HTML is derived from content in a RADEditor text editor so there are no parent HTML tags, so can look as follows:

```
<p>This is a header</p>
<p>this is some content followed by a table </p>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=350&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=myOnPageContent0" class="thickbox">Test Thickbox</a>
<div id="myOnPageContent0" class="thickboxcontent">
<table class="modal">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>item</td>
            <td>result</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is what the jqDom.html() returns from the HTML above:

```
"This is a header"
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this - have some html and remove all elements (in this case divs) that have a certain class (but leaving their contents). JQuery doesnt have to used, but I would like to.

Manipulating the DOM object is fine - **it is getting the full DOM object in its entirety as a string that I am having the problem with.**

Any help would be much appreicated. Thanks.

Comment: When you say .html() only gets the first element -- do you mean there are multiple sibling elements inside a single identified container, and only the first is selected? Can you post a (highly reduced) sample of the HTML in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var radHtml = editor.get_html();

var jqDom = $(radHtml);
jqDom.wrap('div'); //dont remember if thats ok or u need to asign it in the jqDom again
$(".thickbox", jqDom).remove();
$(".thickboxcontent", jqDom).remove();

editor.set_html(jqDom.html());
```

Maybe that could help

Answer (score 5):

If you want the html of each matching element to your selector, try doing a `map` :

```
var allHtmls = jqDom.find('.thickbox').map(function(){ 
  return this.innerHTML; 
});
```

Also, it sounds like you might want to use `unwrap` which was added to jQuery 1.4+ ( http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ )

`jqDom.find('.thickbox').children().unwrap();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't want the HTML of each matching element, rather just the HTML for the entire jqDom after the changes have been made. Because i'm dealing with a third party editor I get HTML from the editor (all good) and convert to DOM (which is fine), make changes to DOM using JQuery (which is fine). It is the returning of a string representation of the DOM (entire HTML) after I have made the changes via JQuery that is the issue.

Using the wrap/unwrap sounds good for the manipulation though, but thats all g at the moment.

Comment: Then wrap the html you are sending it in a single div, and then call `html` on it. That way it's not stored as multiple elements on the jquery object.

Comment: Haha, yea... 4 days before the selected answer... but thanks!